# Bulk rename XML files based on node value

Tags: xml, powershell, rename

I've been trying to prepare a powershell script that would rename all of XML files to the value of one of XML nodes:

```cs
$items = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\" -Filter *.xml
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $x = New-Object -TypeName 'System.XML.XMLDocument'
    $x.Load($item.FullName)
    $OutputFileName = $x.SelectSingleNode("//CreationDate").InnerText
    $OutputFileName = $OutputFileName -replace "-", "_"
    $OutputFileName = $OutputFileName -replace ":", "_"
    $OutputFileName = $OutputFileName -replace "T", "_"
    Rename-Item $item.Fullname -NewName "$OutputFileName.xml"
}
```

Issue I have is that `$x` is always blank, It seems like I can't correctly pull a value of XML node.

XML structure (please keep in mind that `<ActualStartDate>` node changes across files, rest of the names are the same)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns="link">
    <ActualStartDate>
        <TypeCode>0400</TypeCode>
        <VerNumber>2</VerNumber>
        <CreationDate>2012-01-31T14:33:35</CreationDate>
    </ActualStartDate>
</Request>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml file sturcture

Comment: I wrote something like this and Could able to read the data from Xml. $items = Get-ChildItem "D:\TESTBI" -Filter *.xml
foreach($item in $items) {
    
    Write-Output $item.FullName
    $x = New-Object -TypeName XML
    $x.Load($item.FullName)

    $OutputFileName = $x.SelectSingleNode("//Connection").InnerText

    Write-Output $OutputFileName
}

Comment: @Roshan XML example structure added, sorry, should have done this in first place

Comment: You haven't closed the Typecode Tag

Comment: I Don't see any Issue with the Code. Just check the XML Tags. Since you are searching for CreationDate it doesn't matter where the node is. It directly search for first node of CreationDate.

Comment: @Roshan I've tried your script and it returns only the fullName part and nothing after pulling node value.
Unclosed tag is absolutely my fault, when I messed it up when writing an example.
In files it is all fine.

Comment: My script is sample piece to test the value of $x. I Tested Your Code it is working Perfectly.

Comment: @Roshan in that case I'm a bit out of ideas of what might be the issue here, gonna try few more things. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone that helped.

In the end what I found to be the issue was the fact that I had a namespace in XML file with a link that wasn't working. I haven't put the namespace into example, which I wasn't aware was important in that case, sorry for that.

Putting an extra 2 lines in script to ignore that namespace definition solved the issue for me:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml = ([String](Get-Content "file.xml") -replace 'xmlns.*CONFIG">','>' )
```

(Thanks to : http://www.kv0.org/blog/2012/05/04/ignore-xml-namespaces-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with the given example XML, but the problem you are having may come from the fact that using XPath is Case-Sensitive. Perhaps the tag `CreationDate` is called `creationDate` in some other files or it may not even be present at all.

Perhaps try this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test' -Filter *.xml -File | ForEach-Object {
    [xml]$x = $_ | Get-Content -Encoding UTF8

    # get the value of tag CreationDate using XPath (case Sensitive)
    # $OutputFileName = $x.SelectSingleNode("//CreationDate").InnerText
    # or by following the properties of the xml object (case-Insensitive)
    $outputFileName = @($x.Request.ActualStartDate.CreationDate)[0]

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($outputFileName)) {
        Write-Warning "Could not find value for CreationDate in file '$($_.FullName)'" 
    }
    else {
        $OutputFileName = $OutputFileName -replace '[-:T]', '_'

        Write-Host "Renaming file $($_.FullName) to $OutputFileName.xml"
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$OutputFileName.xml" -Force
    }
 }
```